# Problem with default_scope in Rails 3? NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, default-scope

I am experiencing a weird bug after adding this to my `Alternative`-model:

```
default_scope order(:number)
```

On the first page refresh, everything works fine. On subsequent refreshes, I get

```
NoMethodError in Pages#show 
undefined method `written?' for #<Alternative:0x10455c558>
```

`Alternative` most assuredly has the `written?` method. I am running Passenger, so after a

```
touch tmp/restart.txt
```

the page works again. For the first refresh. But the error message is back on subsequent refreshes again. Removing the `default_scope` solves the issue (but only after another server restart).

**Edit:** The bug is also present when running on WEBrick through `rails server`, so it is not connected to Passenger.

**Edit:** `written?` is an instance method on `Alternative`. The bug also appears when trying to access methods gained through `has_many`, like this:

```
has_many :restrictions

alternative.restrictions.empty? # => NoMethodError
```

Anyone else experiencing problems with `default_scope` in Rails 3? Or have a solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have not experienced odd problems with `default_scope`, but I did find that Passenger wasn't reloading code properly in development mode with the current Rails 3 HEAD -- leading to baffling assertions like the one you ran into.

Does it work if you just run "rails server"?

Comment: Good suggestion. Unfortunately the bug rears its head also when running on WEBrick through `rails server`

Comment: If `written` is an attribute on Alternative, is it possible to identify the SQL that is loading the Alternative model that is receiving `written?`? Could it be that it is somehow not loading the `written` column? I realize the inconsistency would still make no sense, but it does look similar to what happens if you did `Alternative.select` and didn't specify the `written` column.

Comment: No, `written?` is a method on `Alternative` and not directly tied to the db-model. Also, any other method call has the same buggy behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Please read this article

http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2008/11/18/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-default-scoping

https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/1812-default_scope-cant-take-procs